DDEExecute for EXCEL, list of action command or items?
At work, we use still terminal emulators for managing our warehouse and I am creating script that can use DDE to communicate with other application like Excel.
I can't seem to find a list of commands that Excel accept in DDE protocol.
So far I am using DDEPoke or DDERequest with R1C1 to read/write to a cell (if you use another language of excel, it will change, in french it's L1C1, in german I think it's Z1C1).
and I know of [SAVE] or [QUIT] but that's about it. (it also don't seem to work if your excel is not in english)
Hopefully there is a list of DDE command we can execute to operate Excel.
I tried different online search and tried some of the basics command I know. But could't find all of them.
